# MySQL: finding a record not present in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables:

```
id   customer  ipAddress
--------------------------
1    acme      10.10.10.10
2    target    33.33.33.33

number   ip
--------------------
54321    10.10.10.10
41247    33.33.33.33
62068    77.77.77.77
```

In this case, 77.77.77.77 has no entries in table 1.

How can I get all the numbers in table 2 that do not have an ipAddress in table 1?

I have tried:

```
select ip from table1,table2 where ip not in(select ipAddress from table1);
```

but I get an empty set.

Comment: Change this `select ip from table1,table2` to this `select ip from table2`. You don't need the extra join to `table1` in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a correct answer (77.77.77.77) with a `left join` and a `where is null`:

```
select ip from table2 left join table1 on (ip = ipAddress) where ipAddress is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

"*Records without match*" problems very often can be solved with a simple `OUTER JOIN` and then `WHERE ... IS NULL`.

In you case:

```
SELECT t2.ip
FROM table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ipAddress = t2.ip
WHERE t1.ipAddress IS NULL ;
```

[**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffeb13/3)